# How to change the width of the custom view while changing the orientation

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5

I have been trying to get the common header view across all tabs.

to achieve it,

i have created custom view.

```
1) sharedView.xib

2) sharedView.h

3) sharedview.m
```

In the attribute inspector of sharedView.xib,

**Changed:**

Simulated Metric -> Size -> Freedom

Simulated Metric -> status bar -> None

Reduced the height of sharedView.

**Question:**

While running , when the change the orientation, [ to landscape], the view is not scaling till the end of right corner. It occupies the exact size mentioned in the xib.

Kindy suggest where am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you considered using autolayout?

Comment: not yet, i am targeting iPhone version 4, if i use auto layout, does it run in from   iPhone 4 to higher version also ?

Comment: It's rather a matter of the iOS version the device is running. Depends which is the lowest version you want to support.

Comment: makes sense, i m targetting from iOS 4.0, and i am not sure where to find whether autolayout supports from which version of iOS?

Comment: Autolayout is supported in iOS 6 and above, if you want to use it and be compatible with lower versions there are ways to accomplish that (e.g. multiple targets and IB files), otherwise, you'd have to figure another way to do it for all iOS versions.